# Last row definition is an invalid qualifier when supplied to my destination

Tags: vba, excel

Just have a simple function to find the last row and then copy a cell to a destination

```
Sub CMS()
'
' CMS Macro
'

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("B2").Copy _
            Destination:=LastRow.Range("B1")
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A2").Copy _
            Destination:=LastRow.Range("B2")
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("B4:R4").Copy _
            Destination:=LastRow.Range("C2")
End Sub
```

I have based it off this [Ron De Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) sample

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

And the copy from the [Excel VBA docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx)

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _ 
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```

However I am receiving back in my that LastRow is an invalid qualifier in my destination, how can I fix this?

Comment: what's your actual goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `LastRow` declared as a `Long`...

```
Dim LastRow As Long
```

...but then try to use it like a `Range` object:

```
LastRow.Range("B1")
```

Use `Cells` instead:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("B2").Copy _
            Destination:=.Cells(LastRow, 2)
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A2").Copy _
            Destination:=.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2)
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("B4:R4").Copy _
            Destination:=.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3)
End With
```

Note - your intended destinations are unclear, so the addresses above may be wrong (I'm not sure what `B2`, etc. are supposed to mean in reference to a row). That will at least get you past the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using `Find` rather than the `xlUp` method.

- works on hidden rows (`xlUp` skips them)
- caters for a blank range (`xlUp` missed full or empty columns as edge cases - so needs further handling)

*code*

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn2()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find("*", ActiveSheet.[a1], xlFormulas)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "last row is " & rng1.Row
Else
    MsgBox "column is blank"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a "formula" & "helper column" approach:

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Data") '<--| reference your worksheet
        With .Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count) '<--| reference its column A cells with "constant" text values offset to the first not-used column
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(MID(RC[-" & .Column - 1 & "],6,1)=""C"",1,"""")" '<--| place a formula returning "1" if the 6th character of corresponding column A cell value is "C"
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Offset(, -.Column + 1).Font.Color = vbRed '<-- select all cells whose formula returned "1" and color corresponding column A cell
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```